# Travelling From London to Vietnam being Spanish, Visa issues?

Tags: visas, uk, spain, vietnam, spanish-citizens

I am flying to Vietnam this August from London although I am from Spain, I have a friend that lives there, since I am flying with him, and it was cheaper than flying from Spain I decided to fly from London.
Are there any visa issues that I could be facing in my departure?

Comment: How long do you plan to spend in Vietnam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As at 9th April 2019 you will not need a visa in the UK, although it is possible that things might change after Brexit (now 12th April, although a delay is possible)

As a Spanish citizen you can enter Vietnam visa-free if your stay is less than 15 days. ([Source](https://vietnamvisa.govt.vn/requirements/vietnam-visa-for-citizens-of-spain/))

If you intend to stay more than 15 days, or if you intend to return to Vietnam less than  a month after your visa-free visit  you'll need an eVisa, applied for online and collected on arrival, cost from $17 (Source as above).

Notes:

- Your passport must be valid for six months beyond the date of arrival
- The regulations covering these visa arrangements expire on 30th June
  2019